# Project specific: PostgreSQL or MySQL need advice

Tags: mysql, sql, django, postgresql

I am making a web app using the Django framework and would like some opinion regarding which database to use.

PostgreSQL works very nicely with Django and I think (please do correct me if I'm wrong) MySQL requires a bit more time and effort to work with Django.

My database in a single table will have around 60 million entries and it does read and write per request once but will sometimes require two reads making it I guess in a sense more read heavy.

Total expected DB size: around 10 tables each with around ~50 million entries.

My question is that will PostgreSQL suffice for having such a large number of entries while performing both read and writes or should I switch to MySQL because I heard MySQL is more advantageous to read heavy tasks.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both MySQL and PostgreSQL are free to download and install. Install then, tune the servers for the expected load, insert 100 million rows of random data, and take some measurements.

PostgreSQL, when configured correctly for your hardware, will perform fine. (PostgreSQL's default settings are *very* conservative.) Its query optimizer and indexing options are far superior to MySQL.

Comment: You have restored my confidence in PostgreSQL. Thank You for your help sir. Needed to hear this.